# Do we really need a 'latin-jazz' tag? Doesn't 'latin'+'jazz' serve?

Tags: discussion

So I got my first chance to vote on a suggested edit today and it's for the tag wiki of a new `[latin-jazz]` tag. Now [the question that uses it](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6286/latin-jazz-anticipated-chord-change-on-last-beat) is also tagged `[latin]` and `[jazz]`. Ambivalence drove me to abstain. The artist in me says "Sure, why the heck not, man, let it be, you know?" But the scientist in me says "This appears to be an unnecessary multiplication of terms."

So what do we think?

*Edit:* I think another important issue is how to we link-up synonyms with "multiple-inheritance" tags like this. Synonyms all 'round?

Comment: Seems like overkill to me as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the main culprit here, as I asked and tagged the question. I was about to remove the `[latin]` and `[jazz]` tags in favor of the `[latin-jazz]` tag, but it looks like my karma is too low here to remove tags on my own questions :-/

Why I feel a `latin-jazz` tag is deserved:

- `latin-jazz` is the result of blending latin music and jazz music, and has developped specificities beyond the specificities of both its parents
- some very notable artists are mainly known in that style and tagging questions regarding such artists with the `latin-jazz` seems meaningful to me

Note that the `[latin]` tag was also created when I tagged my question.

Now, I just browsed through the various tags on music and it seems that there are very few musical style-related tags in there (numbers are the numbers of tagged questions at the date of this writing):

- jazz (28)
- baroque (9)
- flamenco (9)
- classical-music (8)
- electronic-music (7)
- classical-period (5)
- rock-n-roll (4)
- metal (4)
- heavy-metal (0)
- latin (0)
- romantic (0)

I personnaly feel that tagging musical style related questions with one or two tags can be a nice feature for filtering questions : one large scope tag (such as `jazz`, `classical-music`, `rock`, `metal`, `oriental-music`, `indian-music`...) and one specific tag if necessary to give a specific genre context (`salsa`, `death-metal`, `bebop`, `irish-folk`...), so it make sense to have a reasonable coverage of style / genre tags available. In the case of my original question, I feel the most correct tagging would have been `[latin]` + `[latin-jazz]`. But maybe this deserves another question on meta.

Comment: +1 "has developped specificities beyond the specificities of both its parents". That's all I needed to hear. Thank you.